# How do I make the final output of this code indent every ten numbers?

Tags: java, string, loops, newline, bluej

This code is designed to list off the prime numbers between a minimum and maximum input by the user.  When the numbers are output at the end of the code, they are all on the same line.  I would like there to be ten numbers per line, so I assume that it takes a loop of some kind to indent every ten numbers, however I don't know how to do this.  While I have the code posted here, other, unrelated feedback would be helpful.

```
    String primenumbers = "";

    System.out.println("Prime Number Generator.");
    System.out.print("Minimum: ");
    int oldmin = s.nextInt();
    s.nextLine();
    int min = oldmin;
    System.out.print("Maximum: ");
    int max = s.nextInt();
    s.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    for (min = min; min <= max; min++)         
    {             
       int counter=0;
       int num = min;
       for(num = min; num >= 1; num--)
       {
          if(min % num == 0)
          {
              counter = counter + 1;
          }
       }
       if (counter == 2)
       {
           primenumbers = primenumbers +min+ " ";
       }    
    }
    System.out.println("Primes Between "+oldmin+" & "+max+":");
    System.out.print(primenumbers);
```

Comment: create a counter variable and once it gets to 10 then do System.out.println(), then reset counter to 0 and repeat the same process.

Comment: Note that `System.out.print()` will print text on the same line, but `System.out.println()` will print text to a full new line.  So you could either collect all the numbers in a variable and do a `System.out.println()` or incrementally do `System.out.print()`, and then print a newline every 10 items

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatinating prime numbers into a `string`, you can add them into a list and `iterate` the list in the end, e.g.:

`primenumbers = primenumbers +min+ " ";` will be replaced with

```
List<Integer> primenumbers = new ArrayList<>();
primenumbers.add(min);
```

After `System.out.println("Primes Between "+oldmin+" & "+max+":");` statement, you can do the following:

```
for(int i=0 ; i < primenumbers.size() ; i++){
    System.out.print(primenumbers.get(i) + " ");
    if(i+1 % 10 == 0){
        System.out.println();
    } 
}
```